# I can't reassign Numpy array element

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis, numpy-ndarray

I hope you're fine.

I am trying to read data from csv file format by numpy.genfromtxt function everything is alright until now but the returned object in ndarray but elements in numpy.void type.

I am trying to convert this members to ndarray by looping it and re-assign it but its not working.

The code below

```
import numpy as np

data_salaries = np.genfromtxt('D:\Main\Data science and Machine Learning\py dir\Datasets\ds_salaries.csv', 
    delimiter=',', encoding=None, dtype=None) #reading from file
# print(data_salaries)



for (i, record) in enumerate(data_salaries):
    data_salaries[i] = np.array(record) #Not reassigned 
    typ = type(data_salaries[i])
    print(f"Record number = {i}, Record= {record}, type = {typ}")
    
print(type(data_salaries[3])) #shows up numpy.void type
```

My Question How to convert my void arrays element to ndarray, and what the problem with the code above?

Comment: Have you consider using `pandas` to read your csv?

Comment: Yupp, I know Pandas has a data frame that is more beneficial but that's just for practicing on NumPy then I have to use NumPy

Comment: What do you get if instead of assigning you print record and print(np.array(record)). Is the issue in the assignment or the value you are assigning

Comment: it gives me ndarray type but the problem is that I can't change the data_salaries itself, get it? @user157545

Comment: With `dtype=None` you gave created a `structured array`.  Look that up in numpy docs.

Comment: What did the `print(data_saleries)` show?  Look at `data_salaries.dtype`.  A `structured array` has `fields`, not `columns`.  `data_saleries[0]` is a `record` or element of that array.  Fields are referenced by name:  `data_saleries[name]`.  Without more information about the `dtype` and what you need to do with this array, I won't recommend further action (beyond directing you to the docs).